# Getting Radial Grid to appear on polar histogram wiht matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a radial histogram, my code looks something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xticks((0,2*np.pi/3,4*np.pi/3))
ax.set_thetalim(-np.pi, np.pi)
ax.set_rlim(0,2)

plt.hist2d(theta,rad,(200,200))
ax.grid
plt.show()
```

Here theta and rad are the data I've collected. Essentially, all I want is for there to be 3 polar axis lines at the angles 0, 2pi/3, and 4pi/3. However I can't seem to get them to appear.

[image: 2d Histogram]

Comment: Maybe `for x in (0, 2*np.pi/3, 4*np.pi/3): ax.axvline(x, color='white', ls=':', lw=2)` etc.?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect!